# Why “extensibility hooks” makes continuous design harder?

Tags: hook, extensibility

I've recently read "[Continuous Design](http://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/continuousDesign.pdf)" article written by Jim Shore. In one place he wrote:

> In particular, up-front designs often include “extensibility hooks”
>   for future design changes. This approach makes continuous design
>   harder and should be avoided.

I dont understand why it makes continuous design harder. Extensibility hooks (probably with abstractions) generally means better design. So why it makes continuous design harder?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it makes continuous design harder is that you're designing these hooks now for a need that you don't currently have, so your design is based on what you think you're going to need in the future.  If you find out later that you need different functionality than what the hooks allow, you either need to rewrite them or work around them.

It all boils down to doing the [simplest thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) that will accomplish your current goals because that's all the information you have.  The hooks will more than likely just get in the way of future changes.